# Is there a way to test my iPhone for any potential rogue apps

Tags: iphone, applications, security

Is there is a way I can test my iPhone for any potential rogue apps that someone may have installed on it?  I have been working on some nondisclosure type work lately, and it appears that information is being leaked.  I am concerned that something has been installed without my knowledge, and I just waant to make sure of things.

Answer (score 2):

Apple is generally pretty decent with reviewing applications - HOWEVER - if you need to an application such as  http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid   may help a great deal.

Truth to be told - the iphone is not secure period.   Just attend one blackhat event and keep your iphone bluetooth and/or wifi enabled and voila - folks can show you why

[Nicolas Seriot, from the Swiss University of Applied Sciences, has found some alarming design flaws in the iPhone operating system that allow rogue apps to access sensitive information on your phone.](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27080_3-10446402-245.html?tag=mncol;title)   (click on that last sentence for the link.

Answer (score 0):

As Glenn mentioned, iPhone's only security is its relative obscurity. And there are not anti-virus or anti-malware for made for it. For one, without jailbreaking the software developer don't really have access to enough iOS resources. Heck, the mac doesn't have anti-malware software.

All that being said, your best bet is a phone wipe, install stuff on it again from zero, picking apps very carefully, and change every password you can. I'd say ideally, install jailbreak then `ssh` and [change your **root** password from **alpine** to anything safe](http://www.cultofmac.com/how-to-change-your-iphones-default-ssh-password/20871).

Answer (score 0):

Although jailbreaking makes your iPhone much less secure, if you still do it you could use [Firewall iP](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.yllier.firewall) to catch if an application is sending something from your phone that you haven't approved.